# Itemize with cases in beamer

Tags: itemize, cases

I'm working on a beamer presentation in LaTeX and I'm trying to mix somethings that don't seem to want to go together. I'm trying to combine itemize and cases. Here is what I've tried and it didn't work:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \begin{rcases*}
    \item X
    \item Y
    \item Z
    \end{rcases*} These are letters\\
\item 1 $rightarrow$ One
\item 2 $rightarrow$ Two
\item 3 $rightarrow$ Three
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

The issue is that I can't seem to combine everything smoothly. I can either itemize or put things into the case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Put `rcases*` inside n `$ $`.

Comment: Like this? 
$\begin{rcases*}
    \item X
    \item Y
    \item Z
    \end{rcases*}$ These are letters\\

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you try to obtain. Nevertheless, `rcases` can't work outside of math mode, and you can't shuffle environments. If I understand well, you would like to have  a brace in front of some  items of an itemize environment?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Well, to the right of some items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `blkarray`: it consists in nesting an itemize (correponding to the first thee items) in a `blockarray` environment, the rest in another itemize, and a suitable negative vertical spacing between both environments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{blockarray}{@{}p{2cm}\Right{\}}{These are letters}}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{itemize}%[nosep, before = \vspace*{-0.6\baselineskip},after= \vspace*{-0.86\baselineskip} ]
      \item X
      \item Y
      \item Z
    \end{itemize}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  \end{blockarray}
  \begin{itemize}\vspace*{-\dimexpr\topsep + \baselineskip-\itemsep }
    \item 1 $\rightarrow$ One
    \item 2 $\rightarrow$ Two
    \item 3 $\rightarrow$ Three
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]